# Table column formatting for EDM.Time

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

I have a table control in linked to a backend OData service. One of the column contains the value `"Start time"` which is coming from backend as `PT01H15M32S`. Is there any way that I can convert this format to the legible format? Below is how I am trying to achieve it.

```js
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
  label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Start Time"}),
  template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", {
    path: "STRTTIME",
    type: new sap.ui.model.type.Time({
      source: {
        __edmtype: "Edm.Time"
      },
      pattern: "HH:MM:SS"
    })
  }),
  sortProperty: "STRTTIME",
  editable: false,
}));
```

There is also a function `formatValue` for `sap.ui.model.type.Time`, but I am not sure how can I use it to get the correct time format.

Answer (score 2):

By using types you don't need to call formatValue as the runtime will do this for you. However, you should use the correct type: [sap.ui.model.odata.type.Time](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.type.Time.html)! The type you are using does not support EDM data types. Also your coding looks strange.

```
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
    label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Start Time"}),
    template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
          "text" : { 
              path : "{STRTTIME}",
              type: new sap.ui.model.odata.type.Time({
                  source : { __edmtype: "Edm.Time" }, pattern: "HH:MM:SS" })
              })
           }
    }),
    sortProperty: "STRTTIME",
    editable: false,
}));
```

Comment: thanks for highlighting the incorrect type. I am pretty new to this and I am not able to correctly use the type: new sap.ui.model.type.Time.formatValue.